# Wordpress: Retrieve post views in loop?

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system

I have a loop which displays blog post Titles, Excerpts and a Read More link.

I want to also include the amount of views each blog post has in the loop.

I have tried using various view count plugins but none seem to work within a loop.

Would anyone know if there is a way to, say, retrieve this info directly from the database, pairing views with post IDs?

My loop is:

```
 <div id="bloglist">
        <?php query_posts('category_name=blog&showposts=6'); while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                        <div class="panel">
                            <div class="panel-wrapper">

                             <div class="blogstats">
                               <div>ID: <?php  $postid = the_ID(); echo $postid; ?></div>
                               <div>Views: <?php echo_post_views($postid); ?> </div>
                             </div><!--BLOGSTATS--->
                                <div class="excerpt"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
                                <a class="readmore" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>

 </div><!--BLOGLIST-->
```

I am currently unsuccessfully using the WP-post-view plugin

Comment: Have you read the [*installation*](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-postviews/installation/) of plugin it shows the example to display view counts within posts while loop

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using this plugin
[WP-PostViews](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-postviews/)

i attached a picture for change plugin setting

[image WP-PostViews setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cv1eF.jpg)

good luck.